# CSS <p> tag issue

Tags: html, css

After creating a selectbox and adding CSS to it, a `<p>` tag aligns next to the select box throwing off the page. Here is my [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/savagenoob/kZQvW/)

Any suggestions on this css?

Comment: You described what happens, but not why this is a problem for you and what the expect behaviour should be.

Comment: I thought looking at the jfiddle would make it obvious. the <p> tag is further down the page and I have no idea why part of it is showing up at the select box and the rest where its supposed to be.

Comment: Don't assume that everyone can read your mind or can spot the problem.

Comment: This is because your are floating elements

Comment: I think your problem comes from the excessive floating of left, you should probably try to reduce it to to no floats if you can.

Comment: Yeah, I was messing with it on jfiddle trying to line it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `float` the `<select>` element to the left, but don't clear it, so there's probably a better way to do this, but frankly you have a bunch irrelevant code in that jsFiddle that I'm not going to delve into the structure of:

```
....
</select>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

The point is applying the `clear:both` style property to an element surrounding the context, or where a new one is started.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to correct your CSS, you should improve the HTML code:

- enclose each label and form element in a block element as needed with a Strict Doctype (or is it only with XHTML 1.x strict doctype? Nevermind, it's a good practice whatever the doctype)
- associating each label with the corresponding `input[type="text|password|file|radio|checkbox|new html5 one"]`, `select` and `textarea` : `label` should have the same value for the `for` attribute than the value of the `id` on the form element.

Small glitch in CSS:

- the selectbox doesn't have the same width as the input because of a default CSS instruction in many browsers that doesn't take care of horizontal padding.

  ```
  select {
      -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
      box-sizing:content-box;
  }
  ```

will take care of this.

Here is the **fiddle** where I corrected all of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/H2qdd/